# F# List.first deprecated, what is the new method

Tags: f#

I am porting over some old F# code from CTP 1.9.6.8

The code uses `List.first`:

```
List.first (fun x -> if x.Date = d then Some(x) else None)
```

`List.first` has been deprecated.  What is the current method used to achieve the same functionality.

I have reviewed the release notes and could not find any specific reference to the change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try List.pick

```
List.pick (fun x -> if x.Date = d then Some(x) else None)
```

Answer (score 3):

@JaredPar is right.

Note that the F# library docs are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353567(VS.100).aspx

and specifically the List module is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738(VS.100).aspx

and searching for 'first' on that page reveals the usual suspects.

Answer (score 1):

What @JaredPar suggested with `List.pick` is right, though it would raise a `KeyNotFoundException` if the element does not exist.

You can use
`List.tryPick` if you want an `option` to be returned in both cases, found and not found.

It's use is the same:

`List.tryPick (fun x -> if x.Date = d then Some(x) else None)`